# Host URL of websocketpp server

Tags: php, c++, websocket

I've made a websocket server with websocketpp (C++), and a websocket client in PHP. When I test it on my local machine it works: the client can connect to the server and they can send each other some data.

Then I placed the server-script on my server and compiled it there. After compiling it is running and "working": the server is also a client of another server, these connect and transfer data. However, my PHP client cannot connect to the C++ websocket server. I actually do not know which host URL to use. I've tried these:

```
ws://www.url.nl:port/folder/program-name
ws://www.url.nl:port/
ws://www.url.nl:port/program-name
```

How can I refer to my server?

I hope my problem is clear, but feel free to ask for clarifications if needed.

Comment: do you use a direct connection or do you use any (reverse-)proxies in your setup, like apache mod_proxy, squid, etc?

Comment: Locally I use: ws://localhost:8000/

Comment: I think I use a direct connection, since I don't do anything special.. how do I know for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then your url schould be `ws://www.url.nl:port/`

Make shure there is no firewall on your server/network which blocks your request. You can do this by running `telnet www.url.nl port`. If you have access to netcat use `nc -v www.url.nl port` this would give you much more verbose information on your connection status.

It would be very helpfull if you have any error messages. ;-)

**EDIT** running service:

Make shure your service is running and listen on correct network interface and port.

use `netstat -tulpen` on linux or `netstat -ano` on windows

**EDIT** check your firewall rules:
`iptables -L`

Comment: I cannot connect.. it says "connection refused". For localhost it does work. What does this mean?

Comment: "connection refused" means, that your network service is not running properly or that you are blocked by a network component (like firewall)

Comment: netstat tells me: tcp        0      0 :::8000                     :::*                        LISTEN      906        737603432  5808/test7

Comment: ok, the netstat output looks good. let's check the firewall settings `iptables -L`

Comment: hmz... Permission denied, since I don't have root rights... What can I do? By the way, thank you so much already!

Comment: then you have to call your admin (best solution ;-), inverse your connection or try some thing that is known as "the hole trick" to bypass your firewall http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-iptables-bypass-firewall-restriction.html

Comment: Thank you for you support :) Apparently, I wasn't allowed to open a port... So I changed provider and now it works! Firewall it was!